# Syntax to be explained

Tags: powershell, syntax

In this script : [WindowsCredentialVault.psm1](https://gist.github.com/guitarrapc/c37af6978570a4da097b), I see this code :

```
function InitializeWindowsCredential
{
    Write-Verbose ("Loading PasswordVault Class.")
    [void][Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault,Windows.Security.Credentials,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
}

InitializeWindowsCredential
```

However, I don't understand these syntax : `[Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault,Windows.Security.Credentials,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]`.

As far as I know, brackets are for specifying types. Here, there's multiple strings withing the brackets.

Is there any explanation about this syntax?

Comment: If I had to guess, I think it has to do with attributes, since you can specify multiple attributes in a single bracket pair.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is used to get a UWP class or type and appears to work like this:

```
[class/type name, namespace, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
```

I couldn't find any documentation but this msdn blog link give some explanation:
[Loading WinRT Types via Reflection in Windows 8](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ptorr/2012/05/27/loading-winrt-types-via-reflection-in-windows-8/)

EDIT: the purpose of the `[void]` preceeding the call is simply to surpress output as an object is returned:

```
PS C:\Users\me> [Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault,Windows.Security.Credentials,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PasswordVault                            System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.RuntimeClass
```

Comment: does it means that specifying a type using its FQDN name within brackets load the assembly ? (being winRT or not) ?

Comment: @SteveB Highly unlikely.  PowerShell does not auto-load assemblies.

Comment: @Remko, your answer clarify the type declaration. But I don't get the purpose of voiding the type (the [void] cast before the type)

Comment: @Remko, I don't ask what is void, but what the goal of putting it in front of a type. Or precisely, what the purpose of putting the type alone in a script

Comment: in this particular case it's simple there to make sure that instantiating the class doesn't give any output

Comment: @Remko, I don't get you. Where do you see an instantiation ? PLease note that's not the [void] use which is unclear to me. But the right part of the sentence. I still don't get why the type is called as-is